# How can I take a list that isn't a set length, and use each item as an argument for a function?

Tags: python, list, function, arguments, iteration

I'm trying to find a way to take a list of integers and put each one as an argument of a function without knowing the length of the list. I have been trying to do things like `join` and such but that only gives me a single string.

```
def add_numbers(*args):
    num = 0
    for i in *args:
        num += i
    return num

int_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

add_numbers(?)
```

Here is some code that outlines what I am trying to do, take the list and feed the contents into a function that can take any number of ints. How might I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: `add_numbers(*int_list)`.  And if you remove the `*` from both `*args` and `*int_list` then it will work exactly the same way!

Comment: Why can't you just pass the list directly?  `add_numbers(int_list)`

Comment: Note also that the builtin function `sum` does exactly what you want, i.e. `sum(int_list)`.

Comment: I was using the adding function as an example. If I needed to use this type of thinking for other functions where the end result isn't adding, how can i go from a list to the contents being used as arguments?

Comment: `other_function(*other_list)`.  If you tell me the name of the other function and the name of the other list I can give you a more exact answer, but the exact code will depend on the name of the function and the name of the list.

Comment: As others have said, you can use the `*args` syntax to pass each item in the list as a separate argument.  But in the function you'll have to iterate over `args` anyway, so you're not really gaining anything vs. passing the list directly.